# Slowing down screensaver slideshow speed Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, screensaver, slideshow

I am only given 3 options (Slow, Medium, Fast).

I need it to go slower than "Slow".

[image]

"Slow" is around 10 seconds, I'd like to have around 20s.

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The windows 10 screensaver can't be configured outside the Slow, Medium and Fast settings. You can't also change the registry settings, they indicate the speed type and not the time.

I found this free screensaver on the web, it has a wonderful and revolutionary "Seconds" setting, I hope that someone at Microsoft will copy it.

[image: gphotoshow seconds setting]

http://www.gphotoshow.com/gpshow_free.htm

Answer (score -1):

This is certainly not a solution and more of a workaround, but if you just made 2 copies of every photo you wanted to display in the slideshow and set your setting to slow and removed any transition between photos, you'd have pretty much exactly what you're describing without the use of a third-party application

Comment: Did you test and confirm that this worked with a small example. Sounds like a good idea but it'd be better if you could confirm and then include more detail but sounds like a promising workaround to get the needed solution potentially actually. You should go through the steps, confirm a before and after and give example of what to set for transition to look best too perhaps.